# Pycharm doesn't update cache of class input variables

Tags: python, class, variables, caching, pycharm

I have the following class:

```
class meas_point_setting(Meta):
    def __init__(self, environment, device_id, ch_nr, unit_id) -> None:
         some code ....
```

Recently I changed the spelling of the input variables to lower case. But somehow PyCharm does not recognize this, see screenshot:

[image]

How do I delete the Cache where this is stored?
I already tried:

- File-> Invalidate Cache/Restarting
- Restarting PyCharm
- Restarting PC

Nothing seems to help.
The spelling is important because I use the following line in my code:

```
meas_point_setting.__dict__['__init__'].__code__.co_varnames
```

Which also returns the upper case spelling.

```
('self', 'environment', 'Device_id', 'ch_nr', 'Unit_id')
```

Comment: It's also important when you call the function with named arguments.

Comment: Try giving it a completely different name, not just a case change, and then change it back.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, but somehow it's working now.